# problems while production the clustering results

Tags: clustering, online-algorithms, concept-drift

I searched for clustering in production but do not find related  practical answers.

Is it possible to make the clustering code in production?

Suppose I have a data set for 1M users  with around 100 features describing their purchasing behaviors. New data could be generated monthly or quarterly or continuously.  I want to find users groups based on their spending and visiting frequencies, for example I could define user groups like "loyal high spending", "frequent visitor","random visitor", etc.

If I could get new data in like quarterly, is it practical to build user clusters each quarter? Or alternative way is build clustering once and the make classification for new users.

The major problem I could think of  in production is:

Once there is new data comes in like monthly or quarterly, the user feature space will change and user base will change too. This will make cluster centroid drift.

Is there a way to make clustering in production?

Comment: Can you add some details on how new data arrives? And tell us the practical context? Questions with some interesting context tends to generate more involvement!  And, there is a tag [tag:online-algorithms] for situations where data arrives continuously, have a look [at this former posts about clustering and online-a](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=clustering+online-algor*+answers%3A1)

Comment: Do you expect the clusters to change over time? If not, you can discover them up front and then build a classifier to put each future user into one of the pre-defined, fixed groups. The problem gets a lot harder with flexible clusters, since the addition of new data may result in new clusters or redefinition of old ones, re-clustering old users into completely different groups from what you defined in the beginning.

Comment: I closed this because it's too vague and general for this site.  Please see our [help] for question-asking guidelines.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie this is what I'm exploring right now. I expect the cluster will change because user's buying behavior is different for different season. On the other side, it's easier for business side if there is fixed number of groups. New user data will  could come in continuously or in batch.

Comment: Firstly, this is not a huge size of the data, but perhaps some tools for larger datasets would already be useful (e.g. https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss). Secondly, to what extent does it matter when clusterings look slightly different each month or quarter? E.g. if tools get build on top that rely on the inputs not changing too much, that could be a problem, but the solution is not necessarily to enforce similar clustering / embedding into a previously trained space - things change over time, after all, sometimes beyond recognition. Retraining the whole things is sometimes needed...